# Multidimensional array as a structure member memory allocation C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I started learn C about 10 days ago and decided to write a battleship game.
I have a structure player which has a 2d integer array as a member.

```
   struct player{
   ...
   int field[X][Y];...};
```

X and Y both 5 in my case.

When I create a new player in main and call a *print_field(int field[X][Y])* method (that simply prints all members of *field*)

```
int main(){
   struct player player1;
   print_field(player1.field);}
```

I just get some random stuff like
`00000
18356276361600061541186983333419528026550
00010
41963970000
04196320041956320`

I tried different obvious ways of malloc and calloc like

```
player1.field = malloc(sizeof(player1.field));
```

but I get different types of pointers, array or cast exceptions.

Please explain me how does that works.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. You have not provided enough information. All we can say is : there is a bug somewhere in the code you didn't show.

Comment: `player1` is not inited, so what values do you want to see...?

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: That will not even compile. You should get an error on the assignment to the array. An array is not a pointer. What is the `malloc` for?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a local (non-static) variable, or allocate memory through `malloc`, the memory is not initialized in any way. Its content is *indeterminate* and will be seemingly random (in reality it will be whatever happens to be in the memory at the time).

Using that memory in any way, except to initialize it, leads to *undefined behavior*.

You can initialize the whole structure when you define the variable:

```
struct player player1 = { ..., { { 0 } } };
```

---

Also note that

```
player1.field = malloc(sizeof(player1.field));
```

is *wrong*. The compiler should have complained about it. You can't assign to an array. And you don't need to allocate memory for it either. The compiler will make sure memory for the whole structure is allocated when you define the `player1` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You defined player 1 as [local variable](http://iso-9899.info/wiki/Storage_Duration), so init values are indeterminate.

You can "simply" init your struct using [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 5
#define Y 5

struct player{
       int field[X][Y];
};

int main( void )
{
   struct player player1 = (struct player){.field={{0,1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9},{10,11,12,13,14},{15,16,17,18,19},{20,21,22,23,24}}};

   for (size_t i=0; i<X; i++)
   {
       for(size_t j=0; j<Y; j++)
       {
           printf ("%d\n", player1.field[i][j]);

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The values are indeterminate, not random.

Comment: @Olaf Sure,my bad English. Edited.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is how you allocate field.
If you want a fixed size, you can simply call your field

```
int field[5][5];
```

Otherwise, you would need to allocate it that way :

```
int i = 0;
player1.field = malloc(sizeof(player1.field) * size);
while (i++ < size)
    player1.field[i] = malloc(sizeof(player1.field) * size);
```

Comment: You didn't get it.
X and Y are #defined